# Using prototype functions in higher order functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, prototype, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to concat an array of arrays using reduce and I figured that I could use the Array.prototype.concat function like this:

```
arr = [[1],[2],[3]]
arr.reduce((a, b) => Array.prototype.concat(a, b), [])
```

Which works fine and gives me the array `[1, 2, 3]`. Then I thought I could be even smarter and do it like this:

```
arr = [[1],[2],[3]]
arr.reduce(Array.prototype.concat, [])
```

This however gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Array.prototype.concat called on null or undefined
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/axel/Developer/temp/reduce2.js:2:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

It seems to think that `Array.prototype.concat` is `undefined`. Why is this?

Comment: You have to pass arguments into `reduce` function, aswell as into `concat` and return something, because at this moment, your `reduce` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Note that the second line in your initial code should actually read `arr = arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));` which makes further reduction impossible.

Comment: @Kinduser The function does return something. Arrow functions allow only a single expression as their body, and use the result of that expression as their return value.

Comment: `Array.prototype.concat` is not `undefined`. `this` inside `Array.prototype.concat` is `undefined`.

Comment: It's the same as always with methods: when you pass them around, bind them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` operates as a method with respect to some object (i.e., the `this` value of the method's execution). When you pass a function into a function, you do not pass along any `this` value. Thus, you're effectively doing something similar to:

```
var rawConcat = Array.prototype.concat;
rawConcat(a,b);
```

You can use `bind` to create a copy of a function with a particular `this` burned into it:

```
arr.reduce(Array.prototype.concat.bind(Array.prototype), [])
```

However, now that that's cleared up, there are several other issues that stop you from doing this.

For one, `reduce` actually gets *four* arguments, including the current index and the whole array. You ignore these by having your `(a,b)=>` lambda only pass two of those four arguments into `concat`. That's fine, but when you supply a function directly as an argument to `reduce`, it will use all four arguments, so you'll get the result of the call `Array.prototype.concat(a, b, currentIndex, arr)`.

Furthermore, what you're doing isn't a sensible use of `Array.prototype`. The `concat` function concatenates its arguments and appends them to a copy of the `this` value. Since `Array.prototype` is itself just an empty array (albeit with many own-properties that other arrays use as inherited properties), this is effectively the same as `[].concat(a,b)` or (perhaps even more readably) `a.concat(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.concat` expects the context (`this`) to be an Array and in your first example the context is actually `Array.prototype` which incidentally looks exactly like an Array, hence it works.

Your second example however, passes the concat function by reference so the context is null or undefined.

The more correct way to do this would be to use `Function.prototype.call` to bind the context to one of the arrays or call the method directly on the array, e.g.

```
arr = [[1],[2],[3]];
arr.reduce((a, b) => Array.prototype.concat.call(a, b), []);

// Or

arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
```