# Passing prototype's method to a higher order function javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, this, reduce, higher-order-functions

How can I use a prototype's method with `this` referencing to the prototype in a higher order function like `reduce`?

Example code:

```
function A() {

  this.names = ["John", "Jane", "Doe"];

  this.printMergedNamesByIndexes = function() {
    const indicies = [0,1,2]
    console.log(indicies.reduce(this.mergeNames, ""))
  };

  this.mergeNames = function(accumulator, index) {
    return accumulator + this.names[index] + ", "
  };
}

const a = new A()
a.printMergedNamesByIndexes()
```

I'd like to pass the `mergeNames` method of the prototype to the `reduce`function, but in that case the this value in the `mergeNames`method does not reference to the prototype itself. So I got an error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.names[index]')`

I found this post: [Using prototype functions in higher order functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541207/using-prototype-functions-in-higher-order-functions-in-javascript) , but the `bind`method gave me a similar error like above, except it was complaining about the nonexistence of the `bind` method.

Comment: `mergeNames` is not a prototype method (I don't see any `prototype` in your code) but an instance method, although it doesn't make a difference: you should indeed use `bind`. Please show us your attempt of using it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using **lambda/arrow function**.

[Arrow functions MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function does not create its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.

That means passing an arrow function to a higher order function will catch the `this` value of the current scope. In this case it means it catches the prototype object as `this` so we can use its methods inside the arrow function.

```
function A() {

  this.names = ["John", "Jane", "Doe"];

  this.printMergedNamesByIndexes = function() {
    const indicies = [0,1,2]
    console.log(indicies.reduce(this.merge, ""))
  };

  // Arrow function
  this.merge = (accumulator, index) => {
    // "this" referencing to the prototype
    return accumulator + this.names[index] + ", "
  };
}

const a = new A()
a.printMergedNamesByIndexes()
```

Comment: Or you could do `indicies.reduce(this.merge.bind(this), "")`

Comment: ... or stop using `this` and `prototype` completely.

Comment: @PeterMader Is it a bad practice using prototypes? I don't use often Js so could you explain it?

Comment: Well, I mostly use JavaScript to do functional programming, rather than dealing with object oriented programming and inheritance. But there are ways to get around the prototype (for example, class free programming; more info [here](https://dannyfritz.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/class-free-object-oriented-programming/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595749/douglas-crockford-on-class-free-oop-in-javascript)). But that's a little eccentric, most people stick with prototypal inheritance (or fake class-based inheritance, because they don't understand the prototype).

Comment: @PeterMader You might want to notice that he already is not using 
`prototype` at all

Comment: @Bergi but he's using `this`, which causes the problems class free programming aims to solve.